# Шокировано или шокированно?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как всё-таки правильно -  с одним "н" или с двумя?

Она шокирован(н)о замерла от представшей перед ней прекрасной и одновременно ужасной картины.

Comment: Надуманный вопрос о придуманном слове.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь используется наречие, которое должно писаться с двумя буквами Н, но замереть (или что-нибудь еще сделать) шокированно невозможно, так как есть  причастие "шокированный", но нет наречия "шокированно".

Поэтому предложение надо переделать: **Шокированная, она замерла от представшей перед ней прекрасной и одновременно ужасной картины.**

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта неудачны, поскольку приходится отнести шокированность к замиранию, признав существование спорного явления "*шокированное замирание*" (соотв. шокирова**нн**о замерла). Видимо, на самом деле шокирована была **она** (краткое причастие - с одним "н", полное - с двумя) и от этого замерла:

> Шокирова**нн**ая, она замерла [от вида картины].

или:

> Будучи шокирова**н**а [представшей картиной], она замерла.